# Insert Part in the Chapter Header

Tags: chapters, titles, parts

I would like to have my Chapters titles appear like this:

```
Part I Chapter 1
Part I Chapter 2
...
Part II Chapter 1
```

But only the titles, without making it like that in the ToC

But I don't know how to do it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be very useful to have a minimal working example, because an answer would depend on the class you are using, title packages you are using etc. Currently it also not really clear whether you want to also have a chapter title text or only the two numbers with prefixes `Part` and `Chapter`. Showing a minimal working example and explaining what exactly should be different to the current result, is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [KOMA-Script class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) this is not a problem. You simply have to add `chapter` to the reset list of `part` to start the chapter counting at 1 with every part. Additionally you have to change the number format for chapter headings:

```
\documentclass[headings=chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}% Reset chapter with every part.
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\ifnum\value{part}>0 \partname~\thepart~\fi\chapapp~\thechapter\enskip}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{The First Part}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\part{The Second Part}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

In the table of contents you still would have:

[image: table of contents]

but the chapter title not would be, e.g.:

[image: chapter heading]

Note: You can also change the fonts used in the table of contents or for the titles. See, e.g., command `\setkomafont` in one of the KOMA-Script manuals.